# How to add a label on the top of button in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was just trying flutter for android development and I have a button called **`Play Online`**. I want to add a diagonal label on it saying **`Coming soon!`**. I tried all the possible ways and I googled also but won't get any solution.

The button looks like this:

[image: existing]

My code for this button is like below:

```
           Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                height: 50.0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0)),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Play Online',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),

                  onPressed: () { },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

I want my button to look like this.

[image: desired]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a `Stack` widget to add a `Text` on top of the button and then wrap the `Text` with a `Transform` to rotate it, this is a small example you can tweak it as you wish. You need to import `dart:math` for the pi value.

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
            children: <Widget>[
              ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                height: 50.0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0)),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Play Online',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              Transform.rotate(
                angle: 2*pi / 12.0,
                child: Text(
                  "coming soon",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```